# My company software won't run due to EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, windows

I've been trying to get my company software (HP Operations Orchestra) to run after reinstalling it for a lot of times now but I couldn't get it to open up. Instead, it generates an error log file in its directory which contains this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007753fb75, pid=11308, tid=10292
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x4fb75]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000076c800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=10292, stack(0x0000000002960000,0x0000000002b60000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
EAX=0x0000000002b5c228, EBX=0x0000000000000002, ECX=0x0000000002b5c2f8, EDX=0x0000000002b5c268
ESP=0x0000000002b5c218, EBP=0x000007fee06cbe90, ESI=0x0000000000000020, EDI=0x0000000000000000
EIP=0x000000007753fb75, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000002b5c218)
0x0000000002b5c218:   0000000000000202 00000000774facb9
0x0000000002b5c228:   000007fffffdb000 0000000005dc6ab8
0x0000000002b5c238:   000000006d929986 000000000076cd10
0x0000000002b5c248:   0000000000000002 0000000048833800
0x0000000002b5c258:   0000000048835620 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b5c268:   0000000002b60000 0000000002b50000
0x0000000002b5c278:   0000000502b50000 0000000200000003
0x0000000002b5c288:   00000000486e90d0 000000004872c7b0
0x0000000002b5c298:   0000000002b5caa0 0000000002be8504
0x0000000002b5c2a8:   0000000002be7350 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b5c2b8:   0000000000000000 0000000002b5caa0
0x0000000002b5c2c8:   0000000002b5ca70 0000000002b96f7a
0x0000000002b5c2d8:   0000000002b96f10 0000000000000000
0x0000000002b5c2e8:   0000000000000000 0000000002b5ca70
0x0000000002b5c2f8:   0000000002b5cb40 0000000002b65ae2
0x0000000002b5c308:   0000000002b64e90 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000007753fb75)
0x000000007753fb65:   00 00 4c 89 b1 e8 00 00 00 4c 89 b9 f0 00 00 00
0x000000007753fb75:   0f ae 81 00 01 00 00 0f 29 81 a0 01 00 00 0f 29 


Stack: [0x0000000002960000,0x0000000002b60000],  sp=0x0000000002b5c218,  free space=7f00000000000000000k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x4fb75]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  blob 0x0000000002b9703f
j  java.util.jar.Attributes.putValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+13
j  java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Ljava/util/jar/Manifest$FastInputStream;[B)V+301
j  java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V+291
j  java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V+28
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference()Ljava/util/jar/Manifest;+60
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest()Ljava/util/jar/Manifest;+1
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.maybeInstantiateVerifier()V+70
j  java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+1
j  sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(Ljava/util/jar/JarFile;Lsun/misc/MetaIndex;)Lsun/misc/JarIndex;+34
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+80
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen()V+15
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/net/URLStreamHandler;Ljava/util/HashMap;)V+132
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+82
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Ljava/net/URL;)Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;+9
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(I)Lsun/misc/URLClassPath$Loader;+78
j  sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/URL;+6
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+12
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL;+13
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/URL;+30
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+2
j  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getResourceAsStream(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+9
j  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory()Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;+30
j  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;+0
j  com.iconclude.dharma.app.OperationStudio.<clinit>()V+20
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000046414000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8024, stack(0x0000000047540000,0x0000000047740000)]
  0x0000000046400000 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11732, stack(0x0000000047440000,0x0000000047540000)]
  0x00000000463ed800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10924, stack(0x0000000047340000,0x0000000047440000)]
  0x00000000463e1000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10180, stack(0x0000000047140000,0x0000000047340000)]
  0x00000000463d6000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9760, stack(0x0000000046f40000,0x0000000047140000)]
  0x0000000046319000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4976, stack(0x0000000046d40000,0x0000000046f40000)]
  0x0000000046312000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12024, stack(0x0000000046b40000,0x0000000046d40000)]
=>0x000000000076c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=10292, stack(0x0000000002960000,0x0000000002b60000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000046308800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000046a40000,0x0000000046b40000] [id=11912]
  0x0000000046448800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000047740000,0x0000000047840000] [id=11840]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 38208K, used 10045K [0x0000000035b60000, 0x0000000038600000, 0x0000000045b60000)
  eden space 32768K, 30% used [0x0000000035b60000,0x000000003652f728,0x0000000037b60000)
  from space 5440K, 0% used [0x00000000380b0000,0x00000000380b0000,0x0000000038600000)
  to   space 5440K, 0% used [0x0000000037b60000,0x0000000037b60000,0x00000000380b0000)
 PSOldGen        total 87424K, used 0K [0x0000000015b60000, 0x000000001b0c0000, 0x0000000035b60000)
  object space 87424K, 0% used [0x0000000015b60000,0x0000000015b60000,0x000000001b0c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 6037K [0x0000000005b60000, 0x0000000007020000, 0x0000000015b60000)
  object space 21248K, 28% used [0x0000000005b60000,0x00000000061457f0,0x0000000007020000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042e000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\javaw.exe
0x00000000774f0000 - 0x000000007769a000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00000000772d0000 - 0x00000000773ef000     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd5d0000 - 0x000007fefd63c000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefdec0000 - 0x000007fefdf9b000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff760000 - 0x000007feff7ff000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff3b0000 - 0x000007feff3cf000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff040000 - 0x000007feff16d000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000773f0000 - 0x00000000774ea000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff3d0000 - 0x000007feff437000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007feff650000 - 0x000007feff65e000     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe0d0000 - 0x000007fefe199000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefd170000 - 0x000007fefd1c7000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x000007fef2160000 - 0x000007fef21ba000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcLayers.DLL
0x000007fefa510000 - 0x000007fefa581000     C:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fef27e0000 - 0x000007fef27f8000     C:\windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x000007fee0330000 - 0x000007fee0797000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcXtrnal.DLL
0x000007fef0230000 - 0x000007fef0281000     C:\windows\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x000007fefd140000 - 0x000007fefd165000     C:\windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x000007feff660000 - 0x000007feff6d1000     C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd6f0000 - 0x000007fefd8f3000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefe1a0000 - 0x000007fefef2b000     C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00000000738a0000 - 0x00000000738a3000     C:\windows\system32\sfc.dll
0x000007fef8ba0000 - 0x000007fef8bb0000     C:\windows\system32\sfc_os.DLL
0x000007fefd530000 - 0x000007fefd54e000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd330000 - 0x000007fefd33f000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefb240000 - 0x000007fefb258000     C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefd900000 - 0x000007fefd92e000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefef30000 - 0x000007feff039000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fef2430000 - 0x000007fef24d6000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcApi.dll
0x000000006f510000 - 0x000000006f51b000     C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcThe.dll
0x000000006d7f0000 - 0x000000006de95000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefba30000 - 0x000007fefba6b000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000000006d760000 - 0x000000006d76e000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d3b0000 - 0x000000006d3d7000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d310000 - 0x000000006d31a000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\hpi.dll
0x00000000776c0000 - 0x00000000776c7000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006d7b0000 - 0x000000006d7c2000     C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Diconclude.home=C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\Operations Orchestration -Dicons.dir=./Studio/extra/icons/ -Dstudio.mode=PRODUCT_MODE -Ddocs.dir=Studio/docs/ -Dtemplate.dir=Studio/extra/template/ -Xss2048k -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US 
java_command: com.iconclude.dharma.app.OperationStudio
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\RA2HP\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Virtual User Generator\strawberry-perl\perl\bin;C:\ProgramData\Hewlett-Packard\PC COE\VSC\Drivers\;C:\Program Files\HEWLETT-PACKARD\Operations Orchestration\Studio\..\jre1.6\bin
USERNAME=chengca
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 4 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8267484k(3974016k free), swap 16533108k(12078756k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_18-b07), built on Dec 17 2009 13:24:11 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Tue Jun 09 19:10:06 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Can anyone help me with this so I could pinpoint where the problem originates from? I've been troubleshooting (uninstalling/reinstalling JRE, run as adminstrator, run in compatibility mode, etc. ) this for several days now but I'm throwing in the towel. If anyone's got any idea, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Could it have been running a different Java version before?

Comment: Well I did try using different versions of Java(Java 7 and 8, JRE 1.6, 1.7,1.8) between uninstalling and reinstalling the software but no dice. My current version of Java is version 8 build 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this solution:

http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/48035-solve-jvm-problem.html

It seems that adding the "java.tools" location (wich is inside the folder "java\lib" ) to the JAVA_HOME solved his problem.

You can also check this link to pinpoint exactly the problem: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know if anything happens

Comment: Hello, the link you sent me actually helped. Creating the JAVA_HOME solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it has helped you, you can vote up the question, even mark it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION issue that you are experiencing is known to occur on Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista platforms running Java versions 6.0, 7.0, or 8.0. The stop-gap solution that Oracle mentions is to temporarily disable User Account Control (UAC).

Below is the link to the exact webpage from Oracle to which I am referring: [Oracle on Exception Access Violations](http://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml)

Comment: Thanks but I did try to turn off the User Account Control to "Never Notify". It still wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache memory on the computer that you have been using when attempting to install your program?

Comment: Hi A.W. When you mentioned flushing the cache memory, do you mean something mentioned in this link http://www.geckoandfly.com/9298/flush-and-free-up-windows-7-memory-cache/?

Comment: Yes, the link that you mention seems to explain the process for Windows. See if clearing the cache memory on your machine helps.

Comment: Before attempting to install the software that you had mentioned did you first uninstall the older version of that software from your computer?

Comment: One other thought might be to download and use MemTest86 [link](http://www.memtest86.com) to test for whether or not the RAM on your computer is functioning correctly as this is another common source for EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION errors.